# InfoPath from 2010 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, 2016

How can I migrate/upgrade my existing InfoPath form 2010 to InfoPath 2013. Will opening the form in IP 2013 and publish do the needful?

Comment: Sorry to ask question in old thread. I am going to upgrade from sp2010 to 2013. Do you think I can simply backup/restore entire site collection to 2013 farm to save to trouble converting each form 1 by 1?

Answer (score 1):

There are some changes in InfoPath 2013 that you should think about, so I don't think it's enough to open the form via Infopath 2013 and publish that will achieve the goal in all situations ,

So to avoid any issue , try to do the following steps to migrate SharePoint InfoPath form  2010 to 2013

- Get the list form template from SharePoint 2010
- Extract the XSN as a CAB, then modify the manifest.xsf updating to use new URLs and IDs
- Package back up the files as an XSN
- Publish the list form template to the destination > Test

For more details check [How to Migrate a SharePoint 2010 InfoPath List Form to SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint Online](https://www.c5insight.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/88/entryid/613/how-to-migrate-a-sharepoint-2010-infopath-list-form-to-sharepoint-2013-or-sharepoint-online.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To migrate the infopath form to 2013. You need to open the infopath file in infopath designer. Then you need to update the data connection in infopath designer and then publish it to sp 2013 library.

You are now ready to use same form in sp 2013

Here is an article with detailed steps about how to migrate InfoPath forms from SharePoint 2010 to 2013: [InfoPath and SharePoint 2013 – A Perfect Blend to Upgrade your Forms](http://www.lepide.com/blog/infopath-and-sharepoint-2013-a-perfect-blend-to-upgrade-your-forms/)

Some general steps to do the InfoPath form migration:

Copy the design form from InfoPath 2010

Go to forms library where we have published the design template and view the library in explorer view and you can see a folder called “Forms” apart from your submitted xml forms

Open the forms folders and copy template.xsn file

Open the template.xsn file in InfoPath 2013 , check for web browser form compatible

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Form Library in SharePoint 2010 using SharePoint Designer
2. Export template.xsn file on local machine
3. Open that template.xsn file from Info-path form designer
4. Replace all data connection that currently point to SharePoint 2010 site.
5. Publish to SharePoint 2013 server.
6. create new library while publishing or Publish in existing library in
   SharePoint 2013 site